# How to set preheader for email with smtp?

Tags: c#, smtp

I need to programmatically set preheader in email using SMTP.  Would appreciate pointers on how to accomplish it in c#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by putting preheader text in a invisible div.

```
<style type="text/css">
.email-pre-header { display: none !important; }
</style>

<div class="email-pre-header">Sample PreHeader Text</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Yousuf.  Should this blob of text  be embedded inside messageBody? I am not sure where to add this...

Comment: Yes. I added this to the top of message HTML body and it works. Interestingly, if you leave the text blank, some email clients show a generic message, even if the div is available.